# Ruby Regex with Optional Match

Tags: ruby, regex, match, option-type

Here is the text I'm matching

```
AQUEDUCT - March 25, 2017 - Race 4\n MAIDEN CLAIMING - Thoroughbred\n 
INNER DIRT FOR MAIDENS, FOUR YEARS OLD AND UPWARD FOALED IN NEW YORK STATE AND 
APPROVED BY THE\n NEW YORK STATE-BRED REGISTRY. Weight, 121 lbs. Claiming 
Price $25,000. (S) Claiming Price: $25,000\n Six Furlongs On The Inner track 
Track Record: (Captain Red - 1:07.93 - February 26, 2003)\n Purse:
```

This regex fails, even though the optional claiming_price clause is preceded by a non-greedy ".*?" sequence.

```
/(Thoroughbred).*?(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n)?.*Track Record:/m
```

When I take out the "?" after the claiming_price clause, it works

```
/(Thoroughbred).*?(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n).*Track Record:/m
```

Why doesn't it work when claiming_price clause is an optional match?  How do I get it to match and keep the claiming_price clause optional?

EDIT: how would I make this more complicated regex work? This is the one I am actually working with.  I simplified in my original post to make it easier for readers.  But I'm working with your answer and I'm not sure how to apply it to my true regex.

```
/(Thoroughbred|Quarter Horse)\n(?<rules>.*?)(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n)?(?<track_type>(?:(?!\n).)*?)Track Record:.*? - (?<track_record>\d.*?\d) -.*\nPurse/m
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails" and "works"? Unless there is a Ruby bug, regexes do work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a `?` quantifier on the *claiming price* capturing group (i.e. keep it obligatory, matching exactly once) and wrap it together with the `.*?` that is *before it* within an optional non-capturing group:

```
/(Thoroughbred)(?:.*?(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n))?.*Track Record:/m
               ^^                                           ^^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/lM0V3G7LGw)

Now, it will work like this:

- `(Thoroughbred)` - `Thoroughbred` substring
- `(?:.*?(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n))?` - one or zero (`?`) occurrences of:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
  - `(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n)`  - *claiming_price* group capturing

    - `Claiming Price:` - `Claiming Price:` substring
    - `.*?\n` - any 0+ chars as few as possible, up to the first newline
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last occurrence of
- `Track Record:` - `Track Record:` string.

**Why didn't it work with the first regex of yours?**

The `(Thoroughbred)` matched `Thoroughbred`. Then `.*?` pattern, being lazily quantified, was skipped at first, and `(?<claiming_price>Claiming Price:.*?\n)?` was tried. Since `Claiming Price:` is missing right after `Thoroughbred`, the pattern, quantified with `?`, matched an empty string (since `?` quantifier can match 1 or 0 of such pattern sequences). Then, `.*Track Record:` grabbed the rest of the match (any 0+ chars up to the last occurrence of `Track Record:`).

Comment: thank you for the answer.  it is very helpful.  i edited my OP if i could trouble you further.  i am studying your post but i'm not sure how to apply your points to my true, more complicated regex, yet.

Comment: @appleLover: Same technique - wrap the `.*?` and the next group with an optional non-capturing group - see [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/hsjca8XFhP). Also, the `(?:(?!\n).)*` tempered greedy token makes no sense when you restrict a `.` with a single character, replace with `[^\n]*`.